# Edit Controller File Upload Code in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(AdulLiteracyTeachers adulliteracyteachers, HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                db.Entry(adulliteracyteachers).State = EntityState.Modified;



                foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
                {
                    if (file != null)
                    {

                        string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(
         Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads/"),System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                        file.SaveAs(path);
                        adulliteracyteachers.Image = file.FileName;
                    }

                }

                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
          }
      }
```

The file sucessfully edited by suing this code ... I want to add code when I add new file in edit the previous file will be deleted in the directory ....??

Comment: you want all files to be deleted or files from particular user to be deleted ?

Answer (score 1):

What I think is better is when you save pictures you can save also the path in another table with the Id of `adulliteracyteachers` and then when updloading you just retrieve the old path regarding the id of `adulliteracyteachers` and you use `File.Delete(oldPath)` and you update your `adulliteracyteachers.Image=file.fileName`

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the files from directory by defining its address:

```
   DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo("YouFolderPath");
            if (directory.Exists)
                foreach (var item in directory.GetFiles()) {
                    item.Delete();
                }
```

after that you can reuse it.